# Guards and demand

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You have N guards in a line each with a demand of coins. You can skip paying a guard only if his demand is less than what you have totally paid before reaching him. Find the least number of coins you spend to cross all guards.

I think its a DP problem but can't come up with a formula. Another approach would be to binary search on the answer, but how do I verify if a number of coins is a possible answer?

Comment: What are the constraints on N and the demands of coins?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan i guess n is just a number of guards, that is "variable" likewise the demand which is variable to each guard

Comment: can you skip more than one guard ? ex. 5 2 3 7, spend 5, then skip 2 & 3 ?

Comment: Yes, but obviously in this case you want to pay 5 and 2, and nothing else.

Comment: The order of the guards we pass is fixed, right?

Comment: The order should be fixed, otherwise the best answer is: choose the guard with the highest demand and pay him. Pay no one else. Edit: oops, that only holds if no two guards are tied for highest demand. If there are two that are tied, then there are better solutions than "pay all the most-demanding guards"

Comment: Order is left to right fixed.

Comment: Where did you hear the problem - could you share a hyperlink?

Comment: Sorry no hyperlink,was told by word of mouth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed a dynamic programming problem.

Consider the function `f(i, j)`, which is `true` (one) if there is an assignment of the first `i` guards which give you cost `j`. You can arrange function `f(i, j)` in a table of size `n x S`, where `S` is the sum of all the guards demand.

Let us denote `d_i` as the demand of guard `i`.
You can easily compute the column `f(i+1)` if you have `f(i)` by simply scanning `f(i)` and assigning `f(i+1, j + d_i)` as one if `f(i + 1, j)` is true and `j < d_i`, or `f(i + 1, j)` if `j >= d_i`.

This runs in `O(nS)` time and `O(S)` space (you only need to keep two columns per time), which is only pseudopolynomial (and quadratic-like if demands are somehow bounded and does not grow with `n`).

A common trick to reduce the complexity of a DP problem is to get an upper bound `B` on the value of the optimal solution. This way, you can prune unnecessary rows, obtaining a time complexity of `O(nB)` (well, even `S` is an upper-bound, but a very naïve one).

It turns out that, in our case, `B = 2M`, where `M` is the maximum demand of a guard.
In fact, consider the function `best_assignment(i)`, which gives you the minimum amount of coins to pass the first `i` guards.
Let `j` be the guard with demand `M`. If `best_assignment(j - 1) > M`, then obviously the best assignment for the whole sequence is pay the guards for the best assignment of the first `j-1` guards and skip the others, otherwise the upper-bound is given by `best_assignment(j - 1) + M < 2M`.
But how much `best_assignment(j - 1)` can be in the first case? It cannot be more than `2M`.
This can be proven by contradiction. Let us suppose that `best_assignment(j - 1) > 2M`. In this assignment, the guard `j-1` is paid? No, because `2M - d_{j-1} > d_{j-1}`, thus it does not need to be paid. The same argument holds for `j-2`, `j-3`, ... `1`, thus no guard is paid, which is absurd unless `M = 0` (a very naïve case to be checked).

Since the upper-bound is proved to be `2M`, the DP illustrated above with `n` columns and `2M` rows solves the problem, with time complexity `O(nM)` and space complexity `O(M)`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Very interesting and well displayed.

Comment: Thank you. This is still a pseudopolynomial solution, so it would be interesting to know if there is a fully polynomial one. I think that, most probably, there is one which identifies "compulsory payments" (i.e., those cases where you **have** to pay a guard) and deals smartly with it, but unfortunately I don't have time to further think about this problem.

Comment: The complexity should be a little optimized if a balanced tree is used to represent a given `f(i)` column. The leaves of the tree should be the sums spent `s` such that `f(i, s) = TRUE`.
This is the only improvement that came to my mind at the time

Comment: Since you only need to walk the list of possible assignment, a list is more appropriate. This will likely lower the practical efficiency of the algorithm, but unfortunately not the asymptotical one.

Comment: @akappa  don't you think you will get wrong in `51 , 50 , 52` ... acc . to your solution you get `51 + 52` but correct ans should be `51 + 50`

Comment: @akappa in case d_i < total_spend till now , we still can have a better solution if we `PAY` .

Comment: @anon: my solution would return `51 + 50`. Keep in mind that, for each step, you keep every possible distinct cost you may obtain, not just the best assignment. The pruning argument is just to avoid computing some useless cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
function crossCost(amtPaidAlready, curIdx, demands){
    //base case: we are at the end of the line
    if (curIdx >= demands.size()){
        return amtPaidAlready;
    }

    costIfWePay = crossCost(amtPaidAlready + demands[curIdx], curIdx+1, demands);
    //can we skip paying the guard?
    if (demands[curIdx] < amtPaidAlready){
        costIfWeDontPay = crossCost(amtPaidAlready, curIdx+1, demands);
        return min(costIfWePay, costIfWeDontPay);
    }
    //can't skip paying
    else{
        return costIfWePay;
    }
}
```

This runs in O(2^N) time because it may call itself twice per execution. It's a good candidate for [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), because it is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) with no side effects.

Comment: +1 This solution can be very much efficient if the sum of all demands is small. That's why I asked OP if there were any constraints on inputs

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
int guards[N];
int minSpent;

void func(int pos, int current_spent){
    if(pos > N)
        return;
    if(pos == N && current_spent < minSpent){
        minSpent = current_spent;
        return;
    }

    if(guards[pos] < current_spent)      // If current guard can be skipped
        func(pos+1,current_spent);       // just skip it to the next guard
    func(pos+1,current_spent+guards[pos]);   // In either cases try taking the current guard
}
```

Used in this way:

```
minSpent = MAX_NUM; 
func(1,guards[0]);
```

This will try all possibilities its O(2^N), hope this helps.

Comment: no, its not the same,, it will try all possibilities,, can you give a counter example, i've tried it, it works great :)